# UITableViewCell - how to make right UILabel truncate instead of left one?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel

I have created a UITableViewCell using UITableViewCellStyleValue1, which the Apple docs define as:

> A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with left-aligned and black text; on the right side is a label that has smaller blue text and is right-aligned. The Settings application uses cells in this style.

I am trying to set the cell text to display some short text on the left, and some long text on the right, e.g.

> URL        http://www.mylongurl.com/subdirectory/etc

My problem is that the left UILabel gets truncated instead of the right one so it displays as:

> U... http://www.mylongurl.com/subdirectory/etc

If I make the URL even longer then BOTH the labels get truncated, e.g.

> U... http://www.mylongurl.com...subdirectory/etc

Is there any way to make the right UILabel truncate instead of the left one without using a custom UITableViewCell?  I know how to create a custom UITableViewCell, but it seems like overkill?

I can set the UILineBreakMode to change where the text truncates within the UILabel, but I can't see a way to make the detailTextLabel adjust its width to let the textLabel display itself.

```
[[lCell textLabel] setText:@"URL"];
[[lCell detailTextLabel] setText:@"http://www.mylongurl.com/subdirectory/etc"];
[[lCell detailTextLabel] setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

Probably the closest in spirit to what you seem to be asking for is to muck around with the label frames in your `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. (Doing cell layout modifications in your `UITableViewDataSource`'s `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` won't fly, since `UITableViewCells` do all their own internal layout work after `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.) You can use `NSString`'s -`sizeWithFont:` to help figure out the layout requirements for your `textLabel`.

You can also take different approaches, as you mentioned, such as subclassing `UITableViewCell` or setting `cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES`.

Comment: In the end I did something quite similar to what you suggest.  I set the UITableViewCell setNumberOfLines:0 and then adjust the height of the UITableViewCell in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
using NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode to calculate an appropriate height.  It's surprising there is no easier way to do this!

Comment: Yep; I spend a lot of time writing table view cells. There's a trade-off, though, between generic layout systems and performance, and UITableViewCells are performance hotspots on resource-constrained devices, so I understand to some extent keeping the API/support matrix simple.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to create a subclass of UITableView cell and set your customizations to the labels like you have here in `init`. You will probably want to override `layoutSubviews` and resize the labels if you want the left one to be wider.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, self.frame.size.height);
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 220.0, self.frame.size.height);
}
```

Obviously those are arbitrary values. You will want to play with different sizes to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I did specifically say I knew how to subclass UITableViewCell but I was hoping for a more simple solution!

Comment: Dan, subclassing is not complicated at all. I would recommend subclassing. Setting all of the options in the cellForRow method is much slower than doing your customization in a subclass.